# Exclude transpiled/non-existent .JS files from TypeScript Web Publish

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, msdeploy, one-click-web-publishing

While trying to web publish a TypeScript project in Visual Studio 2015, Update 2; the build succeeds, but the Package/Publish fails at:

```
Error: Copying file typescript-filename.js to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\typescript-filename.js failed. Could not find file 'typescript-filename.js'.
```

The error appears when the project specifies a directory for TypeScript intermediate/output files. To reproduce this error, simply create a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of a new Visual Studio TypeScript HTML Application project, with the following contents:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "transpiled"
    }
}
```

If don't use the `outDir` intermediate/output directory option, I get my source files published, which I do not want. (Also the project output gets mixed in with source, and the project becomes a mess.)

**How can I exclude these TypeScript transpiled files from the Package/Publish?**

Since I run WebPack to create separate deployable .JS bundle files (which are included in my project and perform package/publish successfully), I actually don't want any of these transpiled files included anyway.

---

***Additional research:***

I've already tried excluding the .TS source in the Solution Explorer, setting it to None/Do not copy.  But here's the really strange thing about that:

**ANY change** between "None" and "TypeScript Compile" (setting OR unsetting) on a .TS file in my project **will allow my project to publish** to the server successfully, and none of the transpiled .TS/.JS files are deployed; **but only until I've made another change** that requires the project to build again. Then the missing .JS file error reappears.

So, effectively, I have some voodoo I can perform to force a publish, but I'd still really like to fix this problem.

Somehow, `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets` reaches line 615 with a list of files that (AFAIK) never existed at any time during the build or packaging process, in the variable `@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)`. It's as though one of the targets does a direct replacement of any .TS extension with .JS if it just ran the build, but without regard to what actually happened in the build.

```
<CopyPipelineFiles PipelineItems="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)"
                       SourceDirectory="$(WebPublishPipelineProjectDirectory)"
                       TargetDirectory="$(_PreAspnetCompileMergeSingleTargetFolder)"
                       SkipMetadataExcludeTrueItems="True"
                       UpdateItemSpec="True"
                       DeleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue ="True">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I **upgraded my TypeScript tools** for Visual Studio to 2.1.4 and **now it's all good**.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem as you and I solved it using this [approach](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6934):

1. Edit the .targets file causing your error (you can find it in the ouput panel)
2. Paste in  node the xml provided in the link :

   ```
   <Target Name="CustomExcludeFiles" 
         DependsOnTargets="$(ExcludeFilesFromPackageDependsOn)"
         BeforeTargets="ExcludeFilesFromPackage">

   <Message Text="Custom exclude..." Importance="high"></Message>
   <WriteLinesToFile Condition="$(EnablePackageProcessLoggingAndAssert)"
                     Encoding="utf-8"
                     File="$(PackageLogDir)\CustomExcludeFilesBefore.txt"
                     Lines="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject->'
                     From:%(Identity) 
                     DestinationRelativePath:%(DestinationRelativePath) 
                     Exclude:%(Exclude) 
                     FromTarget:%(FromTarget) 
                     Category:%(Category)
                     ProjectFileType:%(ProjectFileType)')" Overwrite="True" />

   <ItemGroup>
     <FilesForPackagingFromProject Remove="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)" Condition="!Exists('%(FullPath)')" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <WriteLinesToFile Condition="$(EnablePackageProcessLoggingAndAssert)"
                     Encoding="utf-8"
                     File="$(PackageLogDir)\CustomExcludeFilesAfter.txt"
                     Lines="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject->'
                     From:%(Identity) 
                     DestinationRelativePath:%(DestinationRelativePath) 
                     Exclude:%(Exclude) 
                     FromTarget:%(FromTarget) \
                     Category:%(Category)
                     ProjectFileType:%(ProjectFileType)')" Overwrite="True"/>
   </Target>
   ```

   3. Save, restart your Visual Studio and republish

Comment: Thank you. I would like to be able to share this project with a team in a manner that allows them to publish with less pain than editing system files; e.g. a patch with an installer, or a change to my project. I'll look at plugging your fix into a project .targets when I get a moment.

Comment: Thanks. This worked great in my case using Visual Studio 2013 and a tsconfig that emits a single javascript file. I just copied the xml into a separate .targets file and imported that in my .csproj using an <Import> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude files from the package with the following MSBuild snippet:

```
<ItemGroup>  
  <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="Sample.Debug.xml">  
    <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget> 
  </ExcludeFromPackageFiles> 
</ItemGroup>
```

Check out Sayed's blog for a full tutorial:

http://sedodream.com/2010/08/15/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployHowToExcludeFilesFromPackageBasedOnConfiguration.aspx

Comment: Have you used that solution? I can't tell due to what are probably just typos if there is a real existing package it is supposed to precede.

Comment: actually, the simpler solution will probably work for me and seems error free. will report back.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely doesn't work. Tried it a dozen different ways, then did a lot of diagnostics to ensure it was active. The problem is that the file doesn't exist, so excluding it using a glob doesn't exclude it.

Comment: If you will create a simple repro solution in GitHub I will troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks! It may be simpler to generate than checkout in this case. In the process of reducing the problem to the smallest repro, I found you only need one file: Create a new Visual Studio TypeScript HTML Application, and add the tsconfig.json file shown above. Then Publish (Package will also error in the same way).

Comment: If you'd prefer to work with a GitHub project let me know and I'll create one.

Comment: Also, I'm thinking now the problem likely is a product defect, and possibly related to changes in VS 2015 Update 2 to better support tsconfig.json.

Comment: I have VS 2015 Update 2 and recreated the scenario but didn't have any problems deploying using the right click publish method.

Comment: Ugh. I have a few other devices I'll check out to and try again. This one is only a month old.

Comment: Wait, did you perhaps build before adding the `tsconfig.json` file? If you have an `app.js` file (it wouldn't be included in the project) that is adjacent to the `app.ts` file, you must delete that to receive the error.